# como retornar o resultado de uma mutação-deleção em graphql?

Tags: javascript, api, graphql

estou tentando retornar o valor de uma deleção na api, com esse valor retornado eu conseguirei fazer um tratamento para o frontend mas como sou iniciante nessa area, estou tendo dificuldades

gostaria de que quando fizesse a deleção retornasse 1 ou 0 (valor que retornou no console.log())
como resposta.

estou usando knex como query builder+mariadb, o crud esta funcinando, mas a parte de resposta customizada eu nao consigo fazer

segue uma parte do codigo:

```js
const users = `
    id: ID
    Nome: String
    Celular: Float
    CPF: Float
    `
const typeDefs = `
type User {
        ${users}
    }

type Mutation {
        deletUser(id: ID!): User
    }
    `
```

```
Mutation: {
        async deletUser(_, { id } ) {
            const result = await db('CrudList').delete().where({ id })
            
            console.log(result)
            return await result
        }
    }
```

```html
mutation{
  deletUser(id: 4) {id}
}
```

Resposta:

```html
{
  "data": {
    "deletUser": {
      "id": null
    }
  }
}
```

obrigado desde ja

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá, a lógica seria a seguinte:

1. Passe uma condição para a busca( geralmente o ID)
2. Faça uma consulta com essa condição, pegue o retorno e coloque em um objeto.
3. Faça sua exclusão, e todo lógica que isso implicar.
4. Quando o banco retornar verdadeiro a exclusão, retorno o objeto com os dados.
   Segue um código de exemplo:

```
    async excluirPerfil(_, args) {
        

        try {
            // aqui pelo id passado no args, tenho o retorno dos dados armazenado 
            // em perfil( estou buscando um perfil no bd)
            const perfil = await obterPerfil(_, args)
            // se o perfil existir, ou seja, está no banco, vamos apagar
            if(perfil) {
                const { id } = perfil
                await db('usuarios_perfis')
                    .where({ perfil_id: id }).delete()
                await db('perfis')
                    .where({ id }).delete()
            }
            // aqui eu retorno os dados do objeto excluído, agora pode tratar no 
            // front
            return perfil
        } catch(e) {
            throw new Error(e.sqlMessage)
        }
    },
```

Retorno no Playground ( no caso eu apenas mostrei o nome, mas pode ser qualquer campo do seu objeto retornado).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]